# How to split a sorted list into sub lists when two neighboring value difference is larger than a threshold

Tags: python

input:

- a `sorted list`, like this:`[1,2,3,8,10,15,16,17,18,22,23,27,30,31]`
- a threshold, like this: `max_diff = 2`

expected output:

- a list of sub lists; each sub list contains the values that the neighboring difference is smaller than max_diff, like this: `[[1, 2, 3], [8, 10], [15, 16, 17, 18], [22, 23], [27], [30, 31]]`

Here's how I did this, I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
test_list = [1,2,3,8,10,15,16,17,18,22,23,27,30,31]
max_diff = 2

splited_list = []
temp_list = [test_list[0]]
for i in xrange(1,len(test_list)):
    if test_list[i] - temp_list[-1] > max_diff:
        splited_list.append(temp_list)
        temp_list = [test_list[i]]
    else:
        temp_list.append(test_list[i])        
    if i == len(test_list) -1:
        splited_list.append(temp_list)

print splited_list
```

Comment: Code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If this code is fully working and you'd just like to improve upon it, you might be better off posting on CodeReview as Praveen suggested. But please make sure to read their [How to ask](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` and `zip` function within a list comprehension to find the indices of the elements that value difference is larger than 2, then split your list based on index list :

```
>>> li =[1, 2, 3, 8, 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 27, 30, 31]
>>> inds=[0]+[ind for ind,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(li,li[1:]),1) if j-i>2]+[len(li)+1]
>>> [li[i:j] for i,j in zip(inds,inds[1:])]
[[1, 2, 3], [8, 10], [15, 16, 17, 18], [22, 23], [27], [30, 31]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,8,10,15,16,17,18,22,23,27,30,31]
>>> b = a[1:]    #offset by 1 position
>>> b
[2, 3, 8, 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 27, 30, 31]
>>> c = [(i[1] - i[0]) for i in zip(a[:-1], b)]
>>> c   #position diff
[1, 1, 5, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 3, 1]
>>> d  = [i[0] for i in enumerate(c) if i[1] > 2]
>>> d    #split position
[2, 4, 8, 10, 11]
>>> e =  [-1]+d+[len(a)]
>>> e    #add start end to split position
[-1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 11, 14]
>>> [a[l[0]+1: l[1]+1] for l in zip(e, e[1:])] 
[[1, 2, 3], [8, 10], [15, 16, 17, 18], [22, 23], [27], [30, 31]]
#split result
```

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging your lines leads to a more compact form:

```
test_list = [1,2,3,8,10,15,16,17,18,22,23,27,30,31]
max_diff = 2

splited_list = []
prev_element = float('-inf')
for element in test_list:
    if element - prev_element > max_diff:
        splited_list.append([])
    splited_list[-1].append(element)
    prev_element = element
print splited_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Works on all iterables

```
def split_by_threshold(seq, max_diff=2):
    it = iter(seq)
    last = next(it)
    part = [last]

    for curr in it:
        if curr - last > max_diff:
            yield part
            part = []

        part.append(curr)
        last = curr

    yield part


l = [1,2,3,8,10,15,16,17,18,22,23,27,30,31]
print(list(split_by_threshold(l)))
```

Comment: why don't you use a for-loop?

Comment: You're right, it didn't occurred to me that I'm actually building a for loop.

Comment: Basically the solution I was going to post, and I pretty much finished it, but I was so tired I didn't _completely_ finish it :P.